# Refresh contents of multiple divs on same page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to refresh/update the contents of multiple divs on the same page. I have a code I have been working with which works great for a single div but, I need to be able to refresh/update the content of multiple divs. The data is coming from a database. Here is an example of how that works.

data.php

```
    <?php

include('dbconn.php');

$sql = "SELECT gpsStatus FROM streamdb";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    $i = 1;
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $gpsStatus[$i] = $row["gpsStatus"];

   $i++;

    }
}

$sql = "SELECT DisplayName FROM streamdb";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    $i = 1;
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $DisplayName[$i] = $row["DisplayName"];

   $i++;

    }
}

$sql = "SELECT ChaserLocation FROM streamdb";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    $i = 1;
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $chaserLocation[$i] = $row["ChaserLocation"];

   $i++;

    }
} 

$sql = "SELECT StreamStatus FROM streamdb";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    $i = 1;
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $status[$i] = $row["StreamStatus"];

    $i++;

    }
} 

$sql = "SELECT TimeStamp FROM streamdb";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    $i = 1;
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $timeStamp[$i] = $row["TimeStamp"];

    $i++;

    }
} 

$conn->close();

<div class="left"><h3 class="panel-title"><?php if ($gpsStatus[1] == 'true' ) { echo "<i class='small material-icons' style='color:#00FF00; font-size:12px;' title='GPS Location Active'>gps_fixed</i>"; } else { echo "<i class='small material-icons' style='color:#FF0000; font-size:12px;' title='GPS Location Offline'>gps_fixed</i>"; } echo " $DisplayName[1]"; if ($gpsStatus[1] == 'true' ) echo " - $chaserLocation[1]"; ?></h3></div> <div class="right"><h3 class="panel-title"><?php if ($status[1] == 'true' ) { echo "<span class='label label-success' style='vertical-align:-40px;'><i class='fa fa-video-camera'></i> LIVE</span>"; } else { echo "<span class='label label-important'><i class='material-icons' style='vertical-align:-4px; font-size:14px;'>videocam_off</i> OFFLINE</span>"; } ?></h3></div><div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

Then I have a js file called update.js which looks like this that calls the above file...

```
$(document).ready( function(){
$('#chaser1').load('inc/data.php');
refresh();
});

function refresh()
{
    setTimeout( function() {
      $('#chaser1').load('inc/data.php');
      refresh();
    }, 2000);
}
```

Then on my HTML page I call like so which refreshes the div...

```
<div class="col-md-3"> <div class="panel panel-primary">
                  <div class="panel-heading">
                  <div id="chaser1"></div>
                  </div>
```

This works great for a single div when the data in the DB updates the div updates but, I am unable to use this to update multiple divs. I have tried adding multiple calls to different files for each file and change the ID but then it only updates the last div. Is there a simplified way to update/refresh the data in multiple divs on the same page with the data from the database. This would work if I loaded all my HTML into the data.php but, the problem then arises that the panel body of the div contains a video player so it refreshes the video player too which is not want I want because this it will stop the player each time it refreshes and updates the divs.

-Thanks

Comment: have you try this window.location.reload

Comment: Do all the divs have the same id?  #chaser1?

Comment: @natel no, that's the thing is a single ID can only be used for a single div. I have tried adding a second ID to the update.js file and have it point to a second data1.php but then the first one doesn't update.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be the prettiest or most logical solution but, it functions as I am needing.

For my update.js I just added each ID like so and pointed each new ID to its own page like so.

```
$(document).ready( function(){
$('#chaser1').load('inc/chasers/ncopeland.php');
$('#chaser2').load('inc/chasers/ksaunders.php');
$('#chaser3').load('inc/chasers/rcontreras.php');
$('#chaser4').load('inc/chasers/nbusby.php');
$('#chaser5').load('inc/chasers/gyates.php');
$('#chaser6').load('inc/chasers/jcollum.php');
refresh();
});

function refresh()
{
    setTimeout( function() {
      $('#chaser1').load('inc/chasers/ncopeland.php');
      $('#chaser2').load('inc/chasers/ksaunders.php');
      $('#chaser3').load('inc/chasers/rcontreras.php');
      $('#chaser4').load('inc/chasers/nbusby.php');
      $('#chaser5').load('inc/chasers/gyates.php');
      $('#chaser6').load('inc/chasers/jcollum.php');
      refresh();
    }, 2000);
}
```

Then on the page for each div included the ID like so with the ID corresponding to the data which it is looking for and include all the markup and php on that page it is calling.

```
<div id="chaser1" class="panel-heading">
                  </div>
```

It may not be the most logical but, it appears to be working now.